# How to create JWT signed with RsaSsaPssSha256

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa-sha256

I'm trying to sign JWToken using RsaSsaPssSha256, with a self signed X509certificate2 that i read from the keystore.

using .net 4.61;

1. Tried to use **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** from Microsoft:

```
SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = ,
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSsaPssSha256Signature),  
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expirationMinutes),
};
```

and got the following error:

```
"IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.\nAlgorithm: 'PS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', InternalId: 'xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx'.'\n is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms"
```

needless to say that SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256 is working as expected. 


2. Tried to use **Jose-JWT** module and got the following error:

```
"RsaUsingSha with PSS padding alg expects key to be of CngKey type."
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading from .NET 4.60 to 4.61, which is necessary when using RsaSsaPssSha256, i removed the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt packages and reinstalled them (even though it is the same dll file). 
now everything is working as expected.